# How to close a python script that opened from a .bat file?

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a .bat file that runs my python script looped forever:

```
:loop
start python test.py
timeout /t 120 /nobreak
goto :loop
```

The only problem is, the python.exe window that opens to execute the script, doesn't close on its own. I've tried adding some exit commands in the script file, but they don't seem to work:

I.e: exit(), os._exit(0), quit(), sys.exit(1). None of those seem to work

Any idea how to close this window?

EDIT-

Should probably mention inside the python script are multiple Selenium Chrome Webdrivers being opened and used, not sure if this has an effect on it.

As an example, to replicate my issue:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.uk')
driver.close()
print("Test complete")
```

Try running that python script with the .bat file I mentioned above to replicate my issue.

Comment: You could use `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`.

Comment: What is inside the python script?

Comment: @Compo inside my python script I'm using Selenium chrome webdrivers. So when I use pythonw, it just opens all the chromedriver windows instead

Comment: @BASmith, you mentioned some things you'd tried in the `.py` file but thought better about letting us see any of it. You're supposed to provide sufficient information for us to replicate your issue, so I'm sorry for not being a better guesser.

Comment: @Compo Apologies. Please see the post again for replication

Comment: I managed to make the pythonw method work. I simply had to ensure the webdrivers were closed and exited in my script. Now, the webdriver command prompts close automatically

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work by adding

```
driver.quit()
```

in my script, and running the script in the .bat file with:

```
start pythonw test.py
```

Desired outcome achieved